# Mvc 3 Html.action Method not found - Void Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, methodnotfound

I published to web server (Windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise-IIS 7) My Mvc 3 web site but dont work,why?

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
@Html.Action("GetLeftMenu", "Menu", new { ulCss = "navmenu-v", CurrentContentID = ViewBag.CurrentContentID, LangID = Session["langID"] })
```

**MenuController:**

```
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByParam = "LangID;ulCss")]
        public MvcHtmlString GetLeftMenu(string ulCss, int? CurrentContentID, int? LangID = 1)
        {
...
}
```

**Error:**

```
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicValidationHelper.ValidationUtility.GetUnvalidatedCollections(System.Web.HttpContext, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection ByRef, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection ByRef, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection ByRef, System.Web.HttpCookieCollection ByRef)'.
```

Comment: instead of "MvcHtmlString" its return type should be "ActionResult"